# which value should pass to Lookup Relationship field?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I create a Employee object where I want to show Lookup Relationship field for Lead. Employee records are coping from Lead. so how to do ?

Actully I wrote in class,

```
emp.Source_Lead__c = lead.id;  // emp is Employee object & lead is Lead object.
```

but it shows me Name, CompanyName in lookup so it wont access. 
like : 
Source Lead : eabc exyz, ecompany

Help me....

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about new employee / edit employee form - yes, you pass an Id. You're doing it right. The tricky part is that you can't immediately use "dots" to show fields from Lead.

After establishing the link and saving you will have to query for lead fields. Something like this (your question isn't too clear, I don't know if this is on one page or 2).

```
Employee__c emp = new Employee__c();
// ... fill fields as needed
emp.Source_Lead__c = lead.Id;

insert emp;

// And later you can query
emp = [SELECT Id, Name, Source_Lead__c, Source_Lead__r.Name, Source_Lead__r.Custom_Field__c
FROM Employee__c WHERE Id = :emp.Id];

System.debug(emp.Lead_Source__r.Name); // now it will work
```